# C++:I call a string substr twice with different position, convert to const char *, they return the same,why?

Tags: c++, string

Example:

```
const char * aaa(string str){
    string tmp = str.substr(0,5);
    return tmp.c_str();
}
const char * bbb(string str){
    string tmp = str.substr(6);

    return tmp.c_str();
}

string str = "Hello World";
const char * ss = aaa(str);
const char * tt = bbb(str);
```

The result is ss="World", tt="World",but my expectation is that ss="Hello", tt="World", I don't know why. I want aaa() and bbb() return "const char*".

Comment: The pointer out-lives the object. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use of

```
return tmp.c_str();
```

is not right. It leads to undefined behavior upstream, in `main`.

You should change `aaa` to:

```
std::string aaa(string str){
    return str.substr(0,5);
}
```

You should change `bbb` similarly.

While those fixes will be good,, the expectation that `str` will change is ill founded.

1. Both functions accept their arguments by value. Neither of them can modify the original object from `main`.
2. Neither of the functions change the input argument. They construct a new `string` when you call `str.substr(0, 5);`.